# Getting a VNC Image Buffer in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, vnc, vnc-viewer

Can anyone suggest a VNC package that allows for a C#/WPF application to pull the image buffer and display it as I please?

My goal is to take a live remote desktop and display it in an in a way that it can be transformed.  This means I can not use ActiveX or older .NET controls (such as VNC#, which I couldn't get to connect to our VNC server anyway).

If I could just extract the image data and display it inside our application, using the IMAGE tag, the solution would be "good enough" for now.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using WritableBitmap - use a VNC library to get a simple bitmap of the server, then draw it to WritableBitmap and display it any way you want

Comment: Thanks Paul.  Do you have a suggestion for a VNC library that would be useful in this situation?